# On hover slide image left (jQuery) and back if no hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First, thanks for reading my question. I'm trying to make grid of 3 images that slide over each other when a user hovers over it. I've seen this on many websites but I don't know what this effect/plugin is called. So I made a image and a fiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish.

The start:

3 images positioned horizontally. The `first image` is almost completely visible except for some `tab-like` bars on the right. When you would hover over the `second image` it will slide to the left leaving only a small (again) `tab-like` bar on the right. The same goes for the `third image`. See this image I've made.

[image]

If a user doesn't hover any of the images it just goes back to the default of showing the `first image` and the `second` and `third image` in `tab-like` state.

I've also made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q8jsdtrh/1/) to show the way the images should be animated.

But as you can see this is not perfect. Does anyone here have a snippet I could use because my jQuery skills are not there yet. But I think this (should) could be accomplished easier and with less code I think? And even maybe more elegantly.

Thanks for the (long) read...

Comment: Thanks for the -1 guy who did this... love it. Sorry if my question did not involves enough research...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple example ;]

```js
$('li').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
}, function(){
  $(this).removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
li {
 width: 0;
 padding: 15px;
 float: right;
 height: 300px;
 overflow: hidden;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #fff;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}

li.active {
  width: 400px;
  transition: all 1s;
}



ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>page 1</li>
<li>page 2</li>
<li>page 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Off course `li`'s briljant :) that works better... I'll go and play with that. Thanks!

Comment: This is just an example, you may make it with any other elements you want ;]

Answer (score 1):

Try zAccordian jquery plugin. https://natearmagost.github.io/zaccordion/index.html

Comment: That one is actually pretty nice!

Answer (score 1):

So I changed your example a bit:

What I did was:
Changed positions to relative and set overflow hidden to *.wrapper*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img-1").hover(function(){
        $('.img-2').stop().animate({'left': '160px'}, 500);
        $('.img-3').stop().animate({'left': '180px'}, 500);
    }, function(){
        $('.img-2').stop().animate({'left': '160px'}, 500);
        $('.img-3').stop().animate({'left': '180px'}, 500);
    });
    $(".img-2").hover(function(){
        $('.img-2').stop().animate({'left': '20px'}, 500);
    }, function(){
      $('.img-2').stop().animate({'left': '160px'}, 500);
    });
    $(".img-3").hover(function(){
        $('.img-2').stop().animate({'left': '20px'}, 500);
        $('.img-3').stop().animate({'left': '40px'}, 500);
    }, function(){
      $('.img-3').stop().animate({'left': '180px'}, 500);
        $('.img-2').stop().animate({'left': '160px'}, 500);
    });
});
```

```css
.img-1 {position:relative;top:0px; background-color:red; width: 200px; Height: 50px;}
.img-2 {position:relative;top:-50px;left:160px; background-color: #1F6; width: 200px; Height: 50px;}
.img-3 {position:relative;top:-100px;left:180px; background-color: #0FF; width: 200px; Height: 50px;}
.wrapper {
    border: black 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    Height: 50px;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    top:0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-1">
  </div>
  <div class="img-2">
  </div>
  <div class="img-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this completely with CSS, no need for javascript.

The example below manipulates the z-index when a `div` is hovered. The only tricky one is the hover of 'image-3'. The z-index of 'image-2' needs to be changed also to ensure it is on top of 'image-1'.

Therefore, in the HTML 'image-2' is placed after 'image-3'. Than in CSS 'image-2' can be addressed as a sibling.

```css
[class^="img"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.img-1 {
  z-index: 3;
}

.img-1 img {
  border: 6px solid #FF0;
}

.img-2 {
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.img-2 img {
  border: 6px solid #F00;
}

.img-3 {
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-3 img {
  border: 6px solid #F60;
}

div[class^="img"]:hover {
  z-index: 5;
}

.img-3:hover+.img-2 {
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-1">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x50&text='image-1'" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-3">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x50&text='image-3'" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x50&text='image-2'" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```